# How to store sounds in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, pygame, pyaudio

I'm trying to make a beat pad. I've programmed this in such a way that a kick plays with the press of <kbd>a</kbd> and snare at the press of <kbd>s</kbd>. If I make a basic beat by pressing a-s-a-s, is there any way for me to save the sound being made?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))
while True:
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                pygame.mixer.music.load('Kick1.mp3')
                pygame.mixer.music.play()
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                pygame.mixer.music.load('Snare1.mp3')
                pygame.mixer.music.play()
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
    pygame.display.update()


pygame.display.set_caption('Beat pad')
```

Comment: You want to combine the sounds and save them as a single sound file?

Comment: Yes, I just figured it out..
I'm posting the answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I used to read and write sounds:

```
f = open ('Kick1.mp3', 'rb')
file = f.read()
f.close()

f = open ('Snare1.mp3', 'rb')
file1 = f.read()


x = open ('Kick3.mp3', 'ab')
x.write(file)
x.write(file1)
```

Since it's an mp3 file it cannot be read like a text file or be appended/written to like a text file. It should be read as a binary file using 'rb' and also appended like a binary file using 'ab'

Here the sounds of two different files ie..Kick1.mp3 and Snare1.mp3 will be stored in a file 'Kick3.mp3' as one sound (cause I'm appending and not writing to it). Kick3.mp3 doesn't exit and hence it'll be created by python and the sound will be stored in that.